# What does a leading zero do for a php int?

Tags: php

```
echo(073032097109032116104101032118101114121032109111100101108032111102032097032109111100101114110032109097106111114032103101110101114097108046);
```

Essentially, a very large number. Now, why does it output `241872`? I know PHP has float handlers. When I remove the leading zero, it functions as expected. What is that leading zero signifying?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you use a leading zero, the number is interpreted by PHP as an [octal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal). Thus, a `9` is not a valid part of the number and the parser stops there:

```
  0730320 (base 8)
=  7 * 8^5 + 3 * 8^4 + 3 * 8^2 + 2 * 8^1
=  7 * 32768 + 3 * 4096 + 3 * 64 + 2 * 8 (base 10)
=  241872 (base 10)
```

Comment: +1 for the additional information about the parser stopping at the first invalid octal character

Answer (score 2):

A leading zero indicates an [octal integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) value

Comment: Not always. `0` itself is decimal in PHP.

Comment: @KerrekSB That is a nonsense statement. `0` is **zero**, regardless of base. The concept of "nothing" doesn't *have*  base. It's no more or less "decimal" than it is binary, octal or hexadecimal.

Comment: @Kerrek - please check the PHP documentation on the linked page, I think you'll find that a __leading__ zero always indicates octal

Comment: You posted the grammar yourself! You will find that `0` is a decimal - and it's the first digit, so is it not "leading"? ;-)

Comment: @KerrekSB No, it isn't, but you are of course entitled to your wrong opinion.

Comment: @Kerrek: How can one lead if nobody's behind him? :)

Comment: He is technically correct. A zero by itself *is* considered of decimal type in PHP. I'm not sure it makes any difference, but that's what the parsing rules say. A zero *followed* by *one* or more legal octal digits is octal. The formal structure is quite clear that these are the rules. (Though I can't think of any context in which it could make a difference.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That is *still nonsense*. It's fine to say "A zero followed by one or more legal octal digits is octal", but that doesn't imply that `0` is decimal, because it simply isn't. Can you site any reference for this?

Comment: @meagar The PHP parser itself, the PHP specification, and the official documentation all agree on this point. Here's just [one link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php). "decimal     : [1-9][0-9]* | 0" "octal       : 0[0-7]+" (+ means one or more, * means 0 or more).

Answer (score 1):

[Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> Warning
>
> If an invalid digit is given in an octal integer (i.e. 8 or 9), the rest of the number is ignored.
>
> Example #2 Octal weirdness

```
<?php
var_dump(01090); // 010 octal = 8 decimal
?>
```

So your number gets cut off after 0730320, which is 241872 in decimal.

Answer (score -1):

010 gives you 8 (octal number)
0x10 gives you 16 (hexadecimal number)