# issue in reversly printing a number in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does a leading zero do for a php int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583397/what-does-a-leading-zero-do-for-a-php-int)

I am just a beginner in php. I tried to write program for print the given number as reverse. For example if i use 123 as input the result should be 321. I tried the following code. It works fine. But if the given input is 0123 the output is 38. I couldn't correct it. How can i correct my code? here is my code.

```
<?php
$n=123;
$b=0;
while($n>=1)
{
    $b=$b*10+$n%10;
    $n=$n/10;
}
echo $b;
?>
```

Comment: If you use `0123` in your code, it's already too late (see link). You should rather use strings for "reversing" the numbers. That also allows for simpler approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's because the numbers that are starting with 0 are considered in base 8, so 0123 is in fact 83 in base 10.

So, your algorithm is correct for integer numbers - if you want the revert of 0123 to be 3210, you could simply revert it as a string and you can simply use the [`strrev`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) function

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I used strrev function instead of my code and my problem ha solved.

Answer (score 2):

When you add a `0` to the beginning of your number, PHP treats the number as octal.

Octal 123 is decimal 83, which correctly changes to 38.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the dynamic nature of PHP not much caring about the difference between numbers and strings:

```
echo strrev(123);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like this:

```
<?php

$rprint = function ($nr) use (&$rprint)
{
    echo $nr%10;
    if($nr > 10)
    {
       $rprint($nr/10);
    }
};

$rprint(12364);
?>
```

Edit 1:

OR you could use strings instead of numbers. As I suppose it was already suggested.

(I was a bit out of the subjects)

Comment: To the OP : Anonymous functions are available since PHP 5.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think your math is the problem.  You should have parenthesis around the multiplier and mod.

```
<?php 
$num=6541020; 
$revnum=0; 
do{ 
    $revnum=($revnum *10)+($num % 10); 
    $num=(int)($num / 10 ); 
}while($num>0); 
echo $revnum; 
?>
```

http://www.weberdev.com/get_example.php3?ExampleID=4879

Comment: Nope. Both `*` and `%` have higher precedence than `+`, therefore there's no need to group with parenthesis (although it can make it more readable): [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Answer (score 0):

the integer with the leading zero is always treated as octal in php. So just make it as a string and use the buitin php function **strrev()**